# What is the output voltage and PIV of the half-wave rectifier?

Tags: voltage, diodes, rectifier

I was analyzing the following circuit, applied sinusoidal voltage at the secondary is 20 Vrms (DVM measurement). My intention is to calculate the output voltage (Vo) measurement when using the DVM and PIV?

**EDIT**
[image]

(i) Output voltage

Following is my calculation.
At diode conducting condition –

[image]

(ii) PIV

PIV is the peak of the sinusoidal voltage signal when the diode is not conducting.

PIV = 0.5 * VRMS * 1.414
    = 10 * 1.414
    = 14.14 V

Could you please verify the results.?

Comment: What does an ideal diode do when it is forward-biased by about 28 V at the peak of the forward-biasing half-cycle by an ideal voltage source with infinite compliance current? I honestly don't know in the case where you don't use the Shockley equation. And if you do use it, I'd still be interested in what you think the equation suggests about the situation. Do you intend on building this and trying with real components? If you think about this, what do you imagine that the resistor "sees" and how do you imagine the diode impacts that? Move the resistor so that it ties directly to the centertap.

Comment: @jonk, I am not sure how I can apply the Shockley equation here ..!!  Please note the edit in the circuit diagram. This is a circuit I have seen one my book.So I was curious to know the output, I not planning to build this circuit at this point.

Comment: Okay. The earlier connection (now gone) meant that the resistor was directly connected across half of the secondary. So the diode had NO effect on it. The other aspect (earlier) was that the diode was directly exposed to the full secondary voltages. Now, you've fixed that. Better. Now, it's simple and safe. When the diode isn't forward-biased, no current flows and therefore the voltage across the resistor is 0 V. When the diode conducts, the voltage across the resistor will follow the negative-going portion of the sine wave, less a diode drop. Simple.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please comment on my output voltage and PIV calculation?

Comment: Your approach for RMS is wrong. But the peak voltage calculation of 14.14 V, before the diode drop itself, is right. Do you know how to compute RMS from half-wave rectification? (Assuming an ideal diode that has zero volts of drop across it.) And do you know how, if you take into account the loss of radians due to the diode going into forward-bias, so that your RMS calculation accurately reflects the diode's effect?

Comment: I am not sure how to do it. Quick online reserch suggest that, for half wave rectifier RMS voltage at the output is Vp/2. I am not sure this is considering the diode drop or not.

Comment: The root mean square is defined something like this:$$y_{_\text{RMS}}^2=\frac1{t_2-t_1}\int_{t_1}^{t_2}\left[y{_t}\right]^2\:\text{d}t$$For a half-cycle in your case \$y_t\$ is everywhere zero, obviously. Ignoring the diodes, you'd have a simply defined additional half-cycle for which to compute the integral over a non-trivial function. But with the diodes, the integral is non-trivial over a still shorter period than a half-cycle and the values for \$t_1\$ and \$t_2\$ would need to be computed. Yes, since only half of the time there is a sine, the RMS of a half-cycle is half the sine RMS.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out with the lead you have commented.

Comment: Good to hear. Basically, you can just "cheat" and figure that you have a full half-cycle. (0th order approx.) But if you want to get into 1st order details, you need to work out how long into the next half cycle before conduction takes place enough to matter, and how long before the end of that next half cycle that conduction effectively stops. This would mean less than a half-cycle. And if you wanted 2nd and 3rd order, then you'd take into account the Shockley equation and internal Ohmic diode resistance near those half-cycle edges. That's when the math fun really begins. (Then take the FFT.)